# Could we users do some job?

Tags: discussion, support

I get into these *inactive* questions sometime when I get bored (especially during the daytime of my **IST**). So, I poke a lot of posts which have typos and erroneous tags, etc.

The problem is now I've got a suspicion that,
**Could normal users edit posts that are inactive for over an year..?**

Answer (score 3):

Yep, you can.

But *please*, when making any edits to a post not near the top of the main page, try to improve as much as possible. Especially if the post has answers and all.

Comment: And don't forget that edits (even tag edits) bump the question to the front page.